# Cookie “portalroles” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute

Tags: firefox

Getting this warning in Mozilla Firefox:

```
Cookie “portalroles” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
```

Does anyone know when "soon" is going to be approximately, and by rejected I'm assuming Firefox will not allow the creation of such cookies?

EDIT: I failed to mention I checked out the article the warning is linking to and I couldn't find anything indicating a time frame or what rejected means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the schedule from Firefox, you can refer to their "Intent to implement" thread here:
https://groups.google.com/g/mozilla.dev.platform/c/nx2uP0CzA9k/m/BNVPWDHsAQAJ

At the time of writing, it states:

> Starting with Beta 79 today, we are rolling out this change to the default behavior of SameSite cookies to a small percentage of the beta population. The initial target is 10%, slowly increasing to 50% by the end of the beta cycle. We will hold at 50% for at least two more beta cycles, at which point we will consider introducing this to a small percentage of the Firefox release population.

However, some questions about the `portalroles` cookie. Is this one that you are setting? If so, is it intended for usage in a third-party context?

Basically, if this is your cookie and only required on your site, then I suggest setting `SameSite=Lax`.

If this cookie is required in a third-party context / cross-site requests, then you need to ensure you have `SameSite=None; Secure`.

Just setting `SameSite=None` without `Secure` is invalid.

Comment: it is a cookie we set in the application and it is not needed in a third-party context in a general sense (being requested by a different app), however, it would be needed by the same app (on the same web-server) with the request being made from a different sub-domain and possibly from different domains too (it's domain driven). So I guess we will have to go with `SameSite=None; Secure` route.

Comment: If it's a different subdomain, you're generally fine with `SameSite=Lax`. If it's a different domain, then yes - you may need `SameSite=None; Secure`. I would suggest attempting and testing `SameSite=Lax` first to see.

This article may help on understanding the difference between origin and site: https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/

Comment: The standards don't say anything about samesite=none requiring the secure flag. That is just something that Chrome came up with and that Firefox and other browsers are following along with. Will it become the de facto standard? Yes. But right now as it stands someone please show me where it says that not setting the secure flag is invalid on samesite=none cookies.

Comment: @JasonAyer 3rd party cookies on the same base domain are not treated the same way as 3rd party cookies from an altogether different domain. It's a de facto standard as far as I know so if it's documented anywhere I'd like to know. But from my tests if you block 3rd party cookies in your browser only 3rd party cookies from altogether different domains are actually blocked even if the domain attribute does not match. Third party cookies from the same base domain are still allowed to be set in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. That leads me to guess that samesite=lax cookies would not be blocked either.

Comment: I've got samesite=strict in apache2.conf, yet for some reason i get this error. For the life of me i don't know it thinks samesite=none. It's driving me crazy.